# How can I read an dynamic object from Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration

Tags: c#, json, .net, configuration

I using .net core 3.1.

I have a json setting in appsetting.json:

```
{
  "genericObject":{
    "A": [ "B", "C"],
    "D": [ "ABC", "CCC"]
  }
}
```

I have loaded the appsetting.json file to `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration`.

How can I load an `object` instance from the `IConfiguration`?
I tried

```
_Configuration.GetSection("genericObject").Get<object>();
_Configuration.GetValue<object>("genericObject")
```

Both failed. I don't want to create a class to load the json settings since it may change.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, the configuration binder needs the property names, it can't just spin you up a dynamic type like json.net.

Of course you could create your own binder and specialized configuration source and provider, but you are missing the point of this feature. It's a configuration system that takes concrete types and binds them from configuration sources and providers, which in turn is loosely designed to be used with *IOptions* interfaces and injected.

So your next problem would be how to resolve `IOptions<object/dynamic>`, which doesn't make sense at compile time.

If you need anything else, just roll your configuration reader from json.net or similar.